# Polars cast pl.Object to pl.Utf8: polars.exceptions.ComputeError: cannot cast 'Object' type

Tags: python, type-conversion, python-polars

I got a pl.LazyFrame with a column of type Object that contains date representations, it also includes missing values (None).
In a first step I would like to convert the column from `Object` to `Utf8` however this results in a ComputeError. I can not seem to figure out why. I suppose this is due to the None values, sadly I can not drop those at the current point in time.

```py
import numpy as np
import polars as pl

rng = np.random.default_rng(12345)
df = pl.LazyFrame(
    data={
        "date": rng.choice(
            [None, "03.04.1998", "03.05.1834", "05.06.2025"], 100
        ),
    }
)
df.with_columns(pl.col("date").cast(pl.Utf8)).collect()
```

Comment: When Polars assigns the `Object` type it essentially means *"I do not understand what this is."* - and you cannot do much with them. How are you ending up with this type in the first place?

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation of object dtype. So it might be also a good idea in EDA / First inspection to just inspect `df.select(pl.col(pl.Object))` to see if there are potentially _I do not understand_ columns. This is mockup data for a unit / stress test. E.g., you got a Database column which is (wrongly but frequently observed) of type `VARCHAR` (instead of `DATE`) that contains dates but might also contain missing values. I.e., I do not know if I will end up with exactly this data but it is not unlikely

Comment: Well in your example, `rng.choice()` is creating a numpy array of `dtype=object`. Perhaps it make sense to use Polars methods instead so you don't have that problem to begin with? `pl.Series([None, "03.04.1998", "03.05.1834", "05.06.2025"]).sample(100, with_replacement=True)`

Comment: That did the trick, and is probably a more realistic approximation of my stress test. Thanks a lot, also learnt something with regard to `pl.Object`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Polars assigns the `pl.Object` type it essentially means: *"I do not understand what this is."*

By the time you end up with this type, it is generally too late to do anything useful with it.

In this particular case, `numpy.random.choice` is creating a numpy array of `dtype=object`

```py
>>> rng.choice([None, "foo"], 3)
array([None, None, 'foo'], dtype=object)
```

Polars has native [`.sample()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/series/api/polars.Series.sample.html#polars.Series.sample) functionality which you could use to create your data instead.

```py
df = pl.select(date = 
    pl.Series([None, "03.04.1998", "03.05.1834", "05.06.2025"])
      .sample(100, with_replacement=True)
)

# shape: (100, 1)
# ┌────────────┐
# │ date       │
# │ ---        │
# │ str        │
# ╞════════════╡
# │ null       │
# │ 05.06.2025 │
# │ 03.05.1834 │
# │ 03.04.1998 │
# │ …          │
# │ null       │
# │ 03.04.1998 │
# │ 03.05.1834 │
# │ 03.04.1998 │
# └────────────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug in Polars, could you report it to their GitHub please?

For now you can use `tolist`

```py
In [24]: import numpy as np
    ...: import polars as pl
    ...:
    ...: rng = np.random.default_rng(12345)
    ...: df = pl.LazyFrame(
    ...:     data={
    ...:         "date": rng.choice(
    ...:             [None, "03.04.1998", "03.05.1834", "05.06.2025"], 100
    ...:         ).tolist(),
    ...:     },
    ...: )

In [25]: df
Out[25]: <LazyFrame [1 col, {"date": Utf8}] at 0x7F6C4A588580>

In [26]: df.collect()
Out[26]:
shape: (100, 1)
┌────────────┐
│ date       │
│ ---        │
│ str        │
╞════════════╡
│ 03.05.1834 │
│ null       │
│ 05.06.2025 │
│ 03.04.1998 │
│ …          │
│ null       │
│ null       │
│ null       │
│ 03.05.1834 │
└────────────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

numpy and polars don't treat nulls the same way and that's the issue.

If you do

```
pl.LazyFrame(
    data={
        "date": rng.choice(
            ["None", "03.04.1998", "03.05.1834", "05.06.2025"], 100
        ),
    }
).with_columns(date=pl.when(pl.col('date')!="None").then(pl.col('date'))).collect()
shape: (100, 1)
┌────────────┐
│ date       │
│ ---        │
│ str        │
╞════════════╡
│ 03.04.1998 │
│ 03.04.1998 │
│ 03.05.1834 │
│ null       │
│ …          │
│ null       │
│ null       │
│ 03.04.1998 │
│ 03.04.1998 │
└────────────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

Strongly-typed numpy arrays don't support null values (except for `np.nan` in float arrays), but you can work around this with `np.ma.MaskedArray`. First we sample, then construct a mask to hide the `None` values:

```py
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.default_rng(12345)

choices = [None, "03.04.1998", "03.05.1834", "05.06.2025"]
chosen = rng.choice(choices, 100)
mask = [x is None for x in chosen]

arr = np.ma.array(chosen, mask=mask, dtype=str)
```

```
>>> arr[:10]
masked_array(data=['03.05.1834', --, '05.06.2025', '03.04.1998', --,
                   '05.06.2025', '03.05.1834', '03.05.1834', '05.06.2025',
                   '03.04.1998'],
             mask=[False,  True, False, False,  True, False, False, False,
                   False, False],
       fill_value='N/A',
            dtype='<U10')
```

Now Polars can handle this nullish array:

```py
df = pl.LazyFrame(data={"date": arr})
df.collect()
```

```
shape: (100, 1)
┌────────────┐
│ date       │
│ ---        │
│ str        │
╞════════════╡
│ 03.05.1834 │
│ null       │
│ 05.06.2025 │
│ 03.04.1998 │
│ …          │
│ null       │
│ null       │
│ null       │
│ 03.05.1834 │
└────────────┘
```